# In print media (Css), how to set margin to only a div?

Tags: html, css, printing

Hye guys, I am facing problem with print media css. There are two divs in html page, body & footer.

```
<div class="main-template-body" id="main-template-body">
    //content
</div>
<div class="main-template-footer">
    //footer
</div>
```

While printing webpage, I need footer to be fixed at bottom of every page. So, I used following css & it is working well.

```
 .main-template-footer {
       display:block; 
       position:fixed; 
       bottom:0; 
       width:100%; 
       min-height:50px; 
       height:auto; 
}
```

for body part, I used margin-bottom to set margin with page bottom border with following css. To avoid overlapping with footer, but it didnot worked.

```
.main-template-body {
    width:100%; 
    height:auto; 
   display:block; 
   position:relative;
    //margin-bottom: 20px; tried
    //margin-bottom : 2cm; tried it too
}
```

My question is, how can I set margin between 'main-template-body' div & print page bottom border to avoid overlapping of body with footer div.

Following css is setting margin to both Body & footer.

```
@page {
  margin-bottom: 4cm;//<- How to set this margin to specific div only?
}
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Edit : I have updated images of 2 pages below, where in first page footer & content overlaps. The content continues to second page from first page. I need to set margin to content, so that overlapping doesnot happen.

[image: image first page]

[image: image second page]

Comment: ***maybe*** @media screen, print
{
 div.main-template-body{margin-bottom:4cm;}
}

Comment: @SoniVimal, I tried it & it didnot work. thanks though. :)

Comment: can you paste your code in Snippet to see the issue?

Comment: When content more then window size than footer goes to down or fix in window screen?

Comment: @Hit, in print view when Content exceeds one page, then it goes to another page. About footer, it duplicates itself in every page & stick to bottom which is working well. I will post images in post.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but i think this is useful for you.

```css
html, body{
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .main{
        min-height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .main-template-footer {
        height: 50px;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .main-template-body {
        padding-bottom: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="main-template-body" id="main-template-body">
        //content
    </div>
    <div class="main-template-footer">
        //footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not working pal. & in print media, it looks like 'cm,mm' type of units are used rather than 'px'. hmm...